# Oracle updateXML - What is the text() for?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

When I'm using the Oracle updateXML()-Function, I have to address the path to the attribute which I'm trying to update (e.g. `'/supplier/companyName/text()', 'Some Company Ltd'`).

OK, I'm fine with that. But what I actually doesn't understand is the `text()`. It seems that it is a function. Is that correct?

But what else is possible to use there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty good [explanation](http://www.xquery.com/tips_and_tricks/using_text_in_XPath.html) of the usage of text():

In the case of updateXML() I think it makes sense to use it because of what you want the resulting update to look like.